# different behaviour of android "Wifi Manager" class in real device and genymotion virtual device while using same API level

Tags: android, api, genymotion, wifimanager

I want to develop an android application that can scan other device with wifi, select one of them and connect.
I use wifi manager class as the base class of wifi device to scan, as u can see in this code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.EditText;
import java.util.List;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.Manifest;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WifiManager wifiManager;
    WifiScanReceiver wifiReciever;
    ListView list;
    String wifis[];
    Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        context = getApplication().getApplicationContext();

        wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiReciever = new WifiScanReceiver();
        registerReceiver(wifiReciever, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));

        if(!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
        }

        requestingPermission();

    }

    //requesting Permission
    private void requestingPermission(){
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)){
        }
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, },0);
    }

    public void OnClickWifiTurnOn(View v){
        ToggleButton tbTurnWifiOn = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton_TurnOnWifi);
        if(tbTurnWifiOn.isChecked()){
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
        }
        else{
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    public void OnClickScan(View v){

        boolean retValue = wifiManager.startScan();
        requestingPermission();

        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),Integer.toString(result), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),Integer.toString(result), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        unregisterReceiver(wifiReciever);
        super.onPause();
    }
    protected void onResume() {
        registerReceiver(wifiReciever, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
        super.onResume();
    }
    class WifiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
            List<ScanResult> wifiScanList = wifiManager.getScanResults();

            if(wifiScanList.size() > 0){
               wifis = new String[wifiScanList.size()];
               for(int i = 0; i < wifiScanList.size(); i++){
                   wifis[i] = ((wifiScanList.get(i)).toString());
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), wifis[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

when I run this code in different API level (like 16, 23, 25) every thing is ok and get good result, but running on my smart phone(LGE LG-K430 (Android 6.0 API 23)) it shows nothing. please help me.

Comment: location permission on android 6 and later (from api 23) is necessary. because of with wifi info a user can find location of other person in a same network. so add request permission solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

location permission on android 6 and later (from api 23) is necessary. because of with wifi info a user can find location of other person in a same network. so add request permission solve my problem.

```
  Intent myIntent = new Intent( Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
    activity.startActivity(myIntent);
```